# Where is IIS (Internet Information Services) in Windows 10 Creators Update?

Tags: iis, windows-10-v1703

Since the "Turn Windows features on or off" link has been removed in Win10CU, I'm looking for a way to enable IIS on my machine.

Comment: You can get the IIS features list from **dism** command `dism /online /get-features|find /i "IIS"`. And also selectively enable any features like `dism /Online /Enable-Feature /FeatureName:IIS-WebServer`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found a solution that works for now. Since Apps and Features from the control panel and start menu results directs you to the new install screen you have to get to the old uninstall programs screen via a command.

From the Run window type: `appwiz.cpl` to pull up the old screen.

[image]

Comment: Also by running `OptionalFeatures.exe` from run dialog box, opens Windows Features window.

Answer (score 1):

The link has just been removed from the home page of the control panenl, just click on `Programs` and you will still see it:

[image: Win 10 - 1703 Programs]

There are several other ways to install IIS and other Windows components, but I doubt Microsoft will remove the old way anytime soon. Maybe telemetry showed them that this particular link was not very often used from the home page.